# OData relationship between resource path components and EDM tags

Tags: odata

I have got a `Entity Data Model` from OData web service and now I'm trying to understand how 
URL components ( `http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Category(1)/Products?$top=2&$orderby=name` ) are related to EDM tags.

As I understand it, `Category` can be both `EntityType` and `EntitySet`, but not, for instance, `ComplexType` or something else?

Please, clarify it to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resourcePath = "/"
[ entityContainerName "." ] entitySetName [collectionNavigation] /
( entityColServiceOpCall / entityColFunctionCall ) [ collectionNavigation ] /
( entityServiceOpCall / entityFunctionCall ) [ singleNavigation ] /
( complexColServiceOpCall / complexColFunctionCall ) [ boundOperation ] /
( complexServiceOpCall / complexFunctionCall ) [ boundOperation / complexPropertyPath ] /
( primitiveColServiceOpCall / primitiveColFunctionCall ) [ boundOperation ] /
( primitiveServiceOpCall / primitiveFunctionCall ) [ boundOperation / value ] /
actionCall
```

http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v3-documentation/abnf/

If we read this properly (let's hope), the first component must always be the name of the entity set.  The (qualified) entity type may be specified explicitly as part of the `collectionNavigation`, and is mainly useful to navigate inheritance trees.

I can verify this; the WCF implementation returns a proper 404 when specifying the entity type name (say "Person") instead of the entity set name (say "People") first.

You are correct that complex types can't be specified as the first component either, since they aren't entities and thus don't have an identity (in turn making it impossible to refer to their instances without an "associated" entity).

Hopefully this answers your question.